# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2

I have looked around the site and I can't find out how to get an output I just keep on getting the same error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I can't figure out why I keep on getting this error any help will be a appreciated!

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def sTrackTemperature():
    "Constantly Show an Output of the Track Temperature"
    sDataRaw = urlopen(Request("https://api.samsara.com/v1/sensors/temperature?access_token=", 518, [2]))
    sDataParse = sDataRaw.read().decode('utf-8')
    sDataJson = json.loads(sDataParse)
    return sDataJson;
print(str(sTrackTemperature()))
```

If needed, here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/**********/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Kartplex/TrackTemperature.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(str(sTrackTemperature()))
  File "C:/Users/**********/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Kartplex/TrackTemperature.py", line 13, in sTrackTemperature
    sDataRaw = urlopen(Request("https://api.samsara.com/v1/sensors/temperature?access_token=**********************", 518, [2]))
  File "C:\Users\**********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 274, in __init__
    for key, value in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

EDIT:
Code is now as follows

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def sTrackTemperature():
    "Constantly Show an Output of the Track Temperature"
    SENSOR = {'SENSOR': '2'}
    sDataRaw = urlopen(Request("https://api.samsara.com/v1/sensors/temperature?access_token=****************", 518, SENSOR['SENSOR']))
    sDataParse = sDataRaw.read().decode('utf-8')
    sDataJson = json.loads(sDataParse)
    return sDataJson;
print(str(sTrackTemperature()))
```

This Code now has the same exact error but the last line is now:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]; it's not even clear which line throws the error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added the full Error

Comment: Evidently you've passed a list where the `requests` library expected a dictionary. Read their docs and figure it out.

Comment: Then [edit] to provide a [mcve] **of that**.

Comment: No, you keep forgetting to edit the question instead of trying to jam code into comments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe

Updated Question with new code and new error

Comment: Yes, because **now you are passing in a string**, and *still* not a dictionary. What on earth is unclear to you?! Did you even read the error message?

Comment: @jonrsharpe
what is unclear to me is **how to pass it as a dictionary** if you could please explain that to me that would be amazing instead of yelling at me what i am doing wrong

Comment: @CreeperMoon2 Pass `SENSOR` which is the dict!

Comment: You have a dictionary (`SENSOR`), then *don't actually pass it in*. Instead you explicitly extract a string from it, for no obvious reason. Why?

Comment: What your saying is to try this
sDataRaw = urlopen(Request("https://api.samsara.com/v1/sensors/temperature?access_token=**********", 518, SENSOR))

Comment: @CreeperMoon2 Along those lines, but 518 as `data` is bound to cause more trouble as it is not a dict either, but will turn your request into a POST.

Comment: Alrights Thank you I got it working!
Sorry for my understanding of python
still learning thanks for bearing with me

Comment: @CreeperMoon2: `urrlib` is not very user friendly. I *highly* recommend using the third party `requests` library instead. It offers a much more intuitive api and informative error messages. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

You only pass positional arguments to the `Request` constructor:

```
Request("https://api.samsara.com/v1/sensors/temperature?access_token=", 518, [2])
```

Given the `init` signature of `Request` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request)):

```
def  __init__(self, url, data=None, headers={},
             origin_req_host=None, unverifiable=False, method=None)
```

you are passing

- a URL string as `url`  (good!)
- the integer `'518'` as `data`  (bad: should be a dict!)
- last but not least - the list `'[2]'` as `headers` (bad: should be a dict!)

Well, you guessed it: `headers` must be a `dict` of header-name, header-value pairs. In the `__init__`, the header dict's `.items()` method is called, which fails appropriately for the `list` that you pass in.

Comment: I am following another Layout of one of my other scripts which actually works using this same type of method

def sDataAuth( APIKEY ):
    "Function for auth/verify method"
    start = time.process_time()
    sDataRaw = urlopen(Request("https://api.samsara.com/v1/auth/verify?access_token="+APIKEY))
    sDataParse = sDataRaw.read().decode('utf-8')
    sDataJson = json.loads(sDataParse)
    elapsed = (time.process_time() - start)
    print("Pass ("+str(elapsed)+")")
    return sDataJson;

THIS SCRIPT ABOVE is from another Program that works

Comment: Yeah, I had the Request of the `requests` module, but the problem is the same: third argument is `headers`.

Comment: The example you cite only has a single argument, the URL.

Comment: I am currently trying your method completely reprogramming my script i will see if i can get this to work

I do have a question though what is the self argument on the __init__ function

Comment: `self` refers to the instance that is being initialised. The actual arguments that you can pass in start at `url`.

Comment: Btw, what is the meaning of 518?